# Expanding rows of previous billing data into columns. Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to build features out of the previous months billing fee, so my current data looks like this and the column I am trying to create is 'PreviousFee'. I would also like to be able to expand this into two months prior, three months prior, etc.

Thank you!

```
data = {'CustomerName': ['Alligators','Alligators', 'Alligators', 'Alligators','Bricks', 'Bricks', 'Bricks', 'Bricks', 'Bricks', 'Bricks'], 
        'ServiceID': [1001, 1002, 1001, 1002, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003], 
        'Product': ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges', 'Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges', 'Apples', 'Bananas'], 
        'Month': ['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb'], 
        'Year': [2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021],
        'Fee': [12, 17, 10, 34, 12, 56, 67, 23, 56, 34],
        'PreviousFee': ['na', 'na', 12, 37, 'na', 'na', 'na', 12, 56, 67]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using `groupby()` and `shift` should do the trick

```
df['PrevFeeGrp'] = df.groupby(['CustomerName', 'ServiceID', 'Product'])['Fee'].shift(1)

CustomerName    ServiceID   Product Month Year  Fee PreviousFee PrevFeeGrp
0   Alligators  1001        Apples  Jan 2021    12    na    NaN
1   Alligators  1002        Bananas Jan 2021    17    na    NaN
2   Alligators  1001        Apples  Feb 2021    10    12    12.0
3   Alligators  1002        Bananas Feb 2021    34    37    17.0
4   Bricks  2001            Oranges Jan 2021    12    na    NaN
5   Bricks  2002            Apples  Jan 2021    56    na    NaN
6   Bricks  2003            Bananas Jan 2021    67    na    NaN
7   Bricks  2001            Oranges Feb 2021    23    12    12.0
8   Bricks  2002            Apples  Feb 2021    56    56    56.0
9   Bricks  2003            Bananas Feb 2021    34    67    67.0
```

If you want to get 2 months prior, just doing `.shift(2)` would work. Remember to sort your df beforehand

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.